# Changing Integer Python

Tags: python

Hey guys just a quick and simple question. I have a function in which I need to add numbers per action. I have already written a script however, it resets to 0 every time. I already know that the mistake is declaring 0 every time however I do not know how to fix this. 
~
Here is an example to help:

```
valid = 0
connection_error = 0
def seesite():
  global valid
  global connection_error
  valid = 0
  connection_error = 0
  try:
    requests.get("https://google.com")
    valid += 1
    print(f"Valid requests: {valid}")
  except:
    error += 1
    print(f"Invalid requests: {invalid}")
```

~
I would like to conduct this however without resetting the value. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not valid python. Can you create an example with actual code instead of pseudocode?

Comment: Its just an example :) I want to do something like that.

Comment: the best way would be to keep track of the total outside the function

Comment: And use a global identifier?

Comment: Try declaring `value` as global variable OR `retuen value` and pass it in function every time.

Comment: Edited code :) Should help a little I guess.

Comment: Because you're resetting the `global` variables to `0` inside the function. Try removing the 2 statements after `global` statements and you also need to rename `error` and `invalid` to `connection_error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numfunc.value` and define `numfunc.value` after the function definition. This emulates static function variables:

```
def numfunc():
    print(numfunc.value)
    numfunc.value += 1
numfunc.value = 0

numfunc() # 0
numfunc() # 1
```

Note that this has no real advantage over global variables, though. It just puts the variable into the namespace of the function instead of the global namespace, with the same accessibility (since there is no "private" or "protected" in Python).

Comment: I copied and pasted those exact line into my interpreter, and they are fine.

Comment: Yes so sorry! Forgot to add the function identifiers *facepalm*